# Meteor how to wait on callback before dispatching Redux action

Tags: javascript, meteor, redux

[Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) uses callbacks, but it seems like there is no 'wait' for them with Redux actions. So, if using something like [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) and having an action something like this:

```
export function loginWithPassword(email, password) {
  return dispatch => {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, error => {
      if (error) {
        return dispatch({type: ASYNC_ERROR, data: error.reason})
    });
  }
}
```

... the action will complete and return before Meteor's call does (thus not re-rendering the UI if needed). I have scoured for hours trying to find the best way to deal with this to no avail. Based on what I have been able to find, it would seem the options are Meteor [Futures](https://gist.github.com/possibilities/3443021) or [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), however I cannot find anything indicating which might be better or why.

I believe that Futures can only be server side and are less widely used than Promises, so Promises may be the better options based on that. I am not even sure if Futures is an option since actions are client side. But I am also not sure if Meteor will play nice with Promises given it's general sync nature.

Promises I believe could be either client or server. Assuming they were client, would it be better to put them in the actions or in the UI code dispatching the actions - or does it really matter?

Does anyone have any thoughts or insight into how best to handle something like this? A working example of one or the other (or both) would be great because I sure couldn't find one after hours of searching. Specifically it would be great to see an example of a simple Meteor login with password dispatched via Redux that displays a 'User not found" or some other 'async' error in the UI login form (the FIRST time).

The action above actually works, but it returns before Meteor is done returning the error, so the error is not displayed in the UI the initial time.

TIA!

P.S. There are a couple of examples out there that display the error in an alert window or console.log it - but that is not the same thing as updating/displaying it as a prop in the UI that dispatched the action. There are no prop re-renders tied to an alert or console.log. The whole idea is to show the error in the form the user is currently on (login form in this example case)

Comment: Can you point out where Meteor claims to be sync in that matter? I know of no such claim. Meteor method callbacks are async by nature, so you will need to handle it in an async form, be that Redux or any other state manager.

Comment: See the API section here as one example stating Meteor API's are sync... https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-async

Comment: This is relating to the server only. Fibers allow Meteor to use synchronous syntax with async APIs on the server, but it has nothing to do with the client. BTW, the repository you linked to is not an official Meteor resource, although Arunoda is a prominent Meteor community member.

Comment: OK and thanks - but the question was not is Meteor sync or async... it was how best to 'delay' until the Meteor callback is completed before dispatching a follow up Redux action based on the result.

Comment: How is that different to any other Redux async flow? You can have a "pending" state that will be changed when the callback is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Using redux-thunk, you could write something like below. I think the trick here is knowing the status of the user object once it's logged in. One way of doing this is to use `store.dispatch` inside a `Tracker.autorun`:

```
// whenever the reactive data changes, we will dispatch the appropriate action
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
    return store.dispatch({
      type: LOGGING_IN,
    });
  }

  const user = Meteor.user();

  store.dispatch({
    type: SET_USER,
    user,
  }
});

export const login = ({ email, password }) => (dispatch) => {
  Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      return dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_ERROR,
        error,
      });
    }

    return dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    });
  });
};
```

You could imagine a user reducer that has a state like `{user: {loggingIn: Boolean, authError: SomeErrorModel}}}` or something like that

You could clear the `authError` on `LOGGING_IN`, and add it on `LOGIN_ERROR`

For any UI changes based on this reducer, just connect your react component with `react-redux`'s `connect()`

Comment: What happens to the Optimistic UI that Meteor offers when you are using Thunk to do the request asynchronously, doesn't it cause a delay? Also where do you specifically put `Tracker.autorun()`, inside the Presentation or the Container?

Comment: Optimistic UI should change Meteor.user() inside the Tracker and revert if it receives an issue from the server.

Comment: Regarding Tracker.autorun(), this is more of a grand concept thing, but I like to keep all the Meteor logic separate of components. Meteor stuff happens in Tracker.autorun or in actions, informing the reducers, and use redux's connect() on components. With this setup, all Meteor state is kept in redux and all components know is redux state. Otherwise, you end up having Meteor and redux state separated and now you need to keep track of two state stores which can be a nightmare

Comment: I was going to write a big blog post about this, but this guy beat me to the punch and I really identify with his organization: https://subvisual.co/blog/posts/79-a-bridge-between-redux-and-meteor

Comment: ah! but you will see that your values will change "revert" back if the async request didn't validate, which I think isn't a good User Experience, no? I agree that Redux and Meteor state if separated is a pain to keep track but most of the tutorials I've read are suggesting separating [UI State and Domain State](https://www.okgrow.com/posts/where-does-redux-fit-in-meteor) what's your take on this? Also do you think it's ok to keep a list of records inside Redux, isn't that duplicating your data and probably causing more calculations?

Comment: reverting is kind of what optimistic UI is about, isn't it? otherwise we would just wait for a response before updating the UI. i guess what i meant is data will update on the client the same way meteor already handles optimistic UI

Comment: UI state vs Domain state -- personal choice thing when perf isn't an issue. i like having one API for my components to consume (redux). this will duplicate data, and if using immutable objects, you're going to be overwriting reducer data every change -- but unless you're dealing with very large collections / not handling changes gracefully, performance is immaterial. plus you get the benefit of stuff like time travel debugging

Comment: Yeah I'm dealing with 1000+ record in a collection. I'm thinking of a way to deal with it.

Comment: Sorry I hit enter too soon. I'm thinking of a way to deal with it optimally, probably paginate it but not entire sure how to achieve it using Redux store. If you any suggestions I'd highly appreciate it. :)

Comment: usually pagination in meteor happens at subscription level. you can set session or reactive vars to pass into Meteor.subscribe (or a package that wraps it). with redux, you can manage those vars with actions and reducers. the blog above shows one way to deal with subscriptions with this setup